# Swift: How to get UIImageView image size after finishing image loading?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView (in UITableViewCell) which gets image from URL. Obviously, it takes some time to load image from the URL.

I want to get the image size after the image finished loading and set the cell height to the height of image. But I cant get the image height after its loaded and all constraints are applied.

Please help.

Comment: How are downloading the image?  Synchronously?  Asynchronously? (post the code)

Comment: I have used Alamofire library to get the image from URL. The code is somewhat messy to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at `Alamofire` ([here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)) and the `AlamofireImage` ([here](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)) libraries. They are great a asynchronously loading images. There are many great tutorials available on how to use them optimally in a tableview and even an 'alamofireimage' tag on stack overflow.

In short, this is how you would download the image:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)

let URL = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")!

imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)
```

In order to set the size of the cell, you would need to use auto layout constraints (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878607/change-uiimageview-size-to-match-image-with-autolayout?rq=1) question).