# How to resize an image view to fit the image and scale appropriately for an iPhone swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout, uiimage

[image]

I have a UIImageView and a UILabel.

I have added leading and trailing constraints to the margin in the storyboard.

I am setting the image in the image view from an array of images each of which is of different size.

The images are aspect fit to the image view , so there is space on right and left of the image view if the image is smaller than the imageview.

How can I scale an image such that the image view resizes itself based on the size of the image and there is no empty space in the background?

I tried adding a height constraint and changing the constant value in the code . I have tried most of the solutions online , but hasn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: You have to scale imageview according to your image height and width and also keep the same ratio of image or Imageview will stretch or blurry or anything can happen.

Comment: Did you tried scaletoFill to imageView contentmode? moreover constraints is only for UIImageView control not for UIImage.

Comment: No scale to fill also does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16878607/6458723

Answer (score 1):

set imageview content mode to centre and remove leading and trailing Layout instead you can use horizontal and vertical centre layout.